# Validating to accept only float numbers but it does accept the integers too, in php?

Tags: php, forms, validation

In the form the user needs to enter two values. These values should only float numbers. I have searched how to `validate to input float values`, and the way I did it, it accepts integers. I used the `filter_var()` function with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT` . It accepts successfully the float scores, but it also accepts the integers which I don't want it.

savelibscores.php

```
<?php

 define('DB_NAME','');
 define('DB_USER','');
 define('DB_PASSWORD','');
 define('DB_HOST','localhost');

 $connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

 if(!$connect){
    die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
 }

 $db_selected=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connect);

 if(!$db_selected){
    die('Can\'t use'.DB_NAME.':'.mysql_error());
 }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$value1=$_POST['s3'];
$value2=$_POST['s4'];
$value3=$_POST['year'];


if(filter_var($value1,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) && filter_var($value2,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)) {
    echo 'TRUE.';

} else {
    echo 'FALSE.';
}

if(!empty($value1) && !empty($value2) && !empty($value3)){
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `library`(s3,s4,year) VALUES ('".$value1."','".$value2."','".$value3."')")or die(mysql_error());
}
else{
    echo "Please fill all the fields. Please be sure to use float values also.";
}


}
?>
```

Comment: An integer is also a float.

Comment: you can check if every variables are integer. `if ( ! is_int ( $value1 ) ){ echo 'TRUE.'; }`

ex: `is_int(23) = bool(true)` and `is_int(23.5) = bool(false)`

Comment: @PeeHaa, "2" is a valid integer, it's also a valid float.

Comment: @ this.lau_  I also want to check the float value to be positive. I wrote this `if((filter_var($value1,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)&& $value1>0) && (filter_var($value2,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) && $value2>0))`, but it inserts the negative float values in the database. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floats are a superset of integers, and as a float input, "3" is just as valid as "3.14159", even though 3 also so just happens to be a valid integer as well.

Would you rather force people to enter "3.0" instead of "3"? The resulting float value will be *exactly* the same, and you're only making it less convenient for your users.

Comment: @JackDog Yes, by using `filter_var($value,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)` you're making sure it's a valid float.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and JackDog's code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Validating to accept only float numbers

**UPDATE**

```
$value1 = "23.5";

if (is_numeric($value1))
{   
    if (strpos($value1, ".") !== false)
    {
        echo 'TRUE';  //float
    } else {
        echo 'FALSE';  //integer
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question since the input will always be a string. So `is_int` will always return false.

Comment: @this.lau_  return `TRUE` if `$value1 = 23.5;` and return `FALSE` if `$value1 = 23;` variable `$value1` must be `numeric`

Comment: Returns `FALSE` if `$value1 = "23.5";`, which is the kind of input in this question.

Answer (score -1):

`is_float($number)` will let you know if the $number is a float or not. (23 returns false).

If you don't want to accept numbers like 23.0 then:

```
function isDecimal($number)
{
  if(is_numeric($number) and floor($number)!==$number)
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you read the question? `$value1` is from a POST value so it is a string. `is_float` on a string will always be false.

Comment: I read the question, I didn't realize that is_float doesn't try to cast the string for the checking. Thank you i guess :P